# Linq and FullTextSearch - Asp.Net

Tags: c#, linq, full-text-search

I know Linq doesn't have a function that supports FullTextSearch, but my website (which uses Linq to SQL and Linq) needs to make use of FullTextSearch.

I feel I have two options to use FullTextSearch and Linq which are:

1. Create a stored procedure in SQL server and query the SP via Linq
2. Create a function in SQL server and use the function within a Linq statement

Does any one have any opinion as to what is better or is it a preference thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no full-text support within Linq-To-SQL. Creating a table-valued function and mapping it is your best option as the results can easily be included as part of a query, rather than the query itself. E.g. you could then restrict the query further, or apply an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: And if I did this with a SP then I would have to first query the Database and then apply additional formatting in memory making it less efficient?

Comment: Yes - you can't really manipulate the results of a SP on the database server before they are returned.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, there is no direct support for a Contains search but there is a way of achieving it.

It requires to manually write the predicate and creating an `Expression.Lambda` to be consumed by an `IQueryable`.

To consume the expression, I used `LinqKit.PredicateBuilder` (https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

```cs
//fieldName must be an existing Property of TEntity
public IQueryable<TEntity> Contains<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source, string fieldName, string criteria)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<TEntity>(true);
    var param = predicate.Parameters[0];
    var member = Expression.Property(param, fieldName);
    var val = string.Concat(criteria, "*\"");
    Expression<Func<string>> valueLambda = () => val;

    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions)
                  .GetMethod("Contains", new [] {typeof(DbFunctions), 
                              typeof(string), typeof(string) });

    var expr = Expression.Call(null, 
                 methodInfo,
                 Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), 
                 member, 
                 valueLambda.Body);

    return source.Where((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(expr, param));
}
```

---

A simpler solution if you are not trying to make a generic solution:

```cs
IQueryable<Entity> Contains(string criteria)
{
    return DbContext.Entity.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Field, criteria));
}
```